# Repeat an instruction a certain number of times without a "loop"?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, stm32f4

I've used PICs before and now I'm using with STM32F415. 
On a time-critical part of my code I need to put a very exact delay to adjust the period of the DAC-DMA that are working together to create a periodic analog signal.

The delay I want to add goes from 0 to 63 clock cycles (If I were able to do 10-63 clock cycles it would be OK aswell). In PIC24F assembly, there's the instruction "REPEAT" which allows me to repeat the next instruction a certain number of times. That would work great for me as I'd be able to just do:

```
REPEAT #0xNUMBER
NOP
```

I'm trying to find something similar with the STM32F4, but I had no luck searching in the instruction set, Reference Manual, and on the Internet in general.

I've already tried to use for/while loops in C and a timer dedicated to it, but the extra instructiosn required consume too much time (40-50 cycles depending on the way I program it).

If someone has an idea or knows how to do it, It would be very useful for me.

Thanks a lot.

*English is not my mother-tongue language so I'm sorry for any possible mistakes. Let me know and I'll try to improve it :)*

**EDIT 1 (23-jul-17)**

Thanks to everyone answering, I've been very busy and couldn't answer every one of you individually.
I'll try @berendi solution of gated clocks, it seems as the best fit for my application.
I'm learning a lot of things about the STM32 I didn't know, thank you everyone!

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on how your system works? Is this a periodic loop which you want to add some controlled jitter to?

Comment: This code goes into de DMA ISR. 
The system enter the ISR every Half Transfer and every Transfer Complete.
So, every Half Transfer I want to add a very little delay to adjust the period of the signal to the exact value I want. I stop the timer that makes de DMA-DAC work, do the delay and then enable it again. The code works and I can make a delay, but the cycles needed for the instruction from the C code are too much, so I want a more efficient solution like the REPEAT-NOP I mentioned.

Comment: I think it's a better idea to use DMA-DAC and TIMERS combination to produce the signal you want. Putting delay manually can be inefficient.

Comment: @ctasdemir the problem is that while calculating the period, I get error from the division. So I calculate how many cycles I've "lost" in the entire period (because the period is divided into 64 values to construct the signal) and then try to "add" them manually. The second half of the signal is 0 so there's no distorsion in adding a few more cycles.

Comment: Ok, so the divide operation takes a variable number of cycles and you are trying to compensate for this?

Would it be possible to start a timer before the division and then do a busywait on the timer after the division? This way hardware manages the delay for you. A better step would be if your next stage could be driven from a timer interrupt i.e. the action after the delay is actually in the timer interrupt?

Comment: There's a division used to calculate the period at which the DMA-DAC have to move data to reconstruct the full signal. The problem is that the division introduces some error. Say it gives 124 clock cycles when it actually is 124,7. If I'm transferring 64 values per signal period, I'm losing 64*0.7=44.8 clock cyles. Then I'd like to add 44-45 clock cycles of delay at mid transfer.
Using interrupts consume too much clock cycles between entering and exiting the routine, and the instruction it would need to execute. That's why I need a way to apply the delay very exactly.

Answer (score 2):

> I stop the timer that makes de DMA-DAC work, do the delay and then
>   enable it again.

So, if I'm understanding it correctly, you have Timer A controlling your DAC, triggering a conversion at each counter overflow, and you'd like to delay it for a variable number of clock cycles.

Most (if not all) timers of the STM32F4 support **gated mode slave** operation, where you can select another timer (Timer B) as a master, and Timer A counts only as long as the trigger output of Timer B is low. In other words, Timer A will stop counting on a rising edge from Timer B, and resume counting on a falling edge. Now, configure Timer B to output a **single pulse** when enabled, where the pulse width is the delay you want, then Timer A will be delayed for the exact duration of the pulse.

[image]

See the chapters on One-pulse mode, Timers and external trigger synchronization, and the description of the CR1, CR2, and SMCR registers in the reference manual.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is the solution I'm trying to apply now. 

In the Ref Manual there's explanation on _Using one timer to enable another timer_ and _One-pulse mode_. I'm actually trying to _disable_ one timer using another timer, and I think I know how to set up a single pulse. My problem now is, once the master has finished its pulse, will it remain in '1' or will it come back to '0'? Because I want it to be always '1' except for the pulse in '0' I tell him to do at a certain point.

Comment: I want to add that I'm not sure if the best way is using the _Trigger Output_ or the _Output compare_ mode, as it seems both could be configured to drive the slave but I'm not finding the way of putting it all together to do what I want them to do.

Answer (score 1):

NOP is not a very good solution for the delay. Use barrier instructions instead as the execution time is exactly as stated in the ARM documentation (3, 4 or 5 cycles depending what instruction and the core version). You can place n consecutive barriers to archive the delay you need

Answer (score 1):

On a PIC you can do this and it is a very common solution, the execution time was deterministic.  Outside architectures like that, and older chips that were also deterministic (before clones came out) that would be okay as well.  But in general that is not how you do a delay, it is not deterministic, you can get an "at least this long" for a tuned loop, but you cant get "exactly this long" even tuned, or should never expect to.  That is why there are timers, multiple usually, in mcu designs and that is what you use for measuring time.  For the problem you are trying to solve that is the solution here, one timer or cascaded timers if you really need that.

Arm does not have an x86 like repeat instruction your smallest loop is going to be two instructions and I have countless times demonstrated that on the same chip this loop can vary in speed, so tune it, add a line of code and the delay properties of this loop change

```
here:
  sub r0,#1
  bne here
```

for classic (gas) syntax, for unified syntax use subs instead of sub.

You are also on an stm32 where they have a buried cache on the instruction side that you cannot turn off nor control, it generally gives you no wait state performance, certainly for things like this but obviously they dont have a cache the size of the flash so pre-fetch cycles have to happen somewhere, and you have to expect that sometimes you are going to have to feel that prefetch when you jump into this loop.

Comment: If you can tolerate a few clocks of slop here and there you can use a loop or a tuned number of nops for a specific chip with specific clock and wait state settings, but if you want an exact number of clocks 1) not necessarily possible 2) use a timer.

Comment: It is possible to avoid flash problems by placing those critical parts of the code in the ram. On many Cortex devices you even have the core coupled ram, to avoid conflicts with DMA, and some have separate for instruction and data, and you can work in the most efficient Harvard like architecture.

Comment: on the stm32 it is easier to demonstrate performance differences in ram, the primary issue on the cortex-m is the fetch length is it a 32 or 16 and that is at compile time for the core, so that simple loop how many extra fetches are you doing.  change the alignment by one word and you can increase the loop time by one or two clocks per loop.  but yes in general non-stm32, the flash is often half the speed or worse than the cpu and ram is 1x (and you still have the alignment but it is automatically faster)

Comment: with larger arms where the fetch length is 8 words for example and the branch predictor if enabled works differently there are sweet spots where the fetching is best and doesnt have to get an extra fetch line per loop, and sweet spots where the branch predictor works vs doesnt.   the branch predictor on the cortex-m that I remember is not a pipe type one but a cached one, I remember last time this address was a branch so I will assume it is still a branch.

Comment: throw in interrupts or other such things and that can affect the next tuned loop execution, but maybe the second one after that is back to the tuned time

Comment: In the time critical sections interrupts are usually disabled

Comment: Its not designed for this and you cannot make assumptions across cortex-ms, nor within the same cortex-m with different settings.  One would also assume there is some high level (C or other) code wrapped around this delay which is going to add some level of uncertainty as well...It is a lot more stable than one might expect, but, you have to understand how to get there and how not to break it...