# Creating a pulse in low state with Output Compare, must be high by default + Timer not enabling when needed

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, dma, stm32f4

This question has its origin in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209384/repeat-an-instruction-a-certain-number-of-times-without-a-loop). I've decided to create a new one because it's a very particular thing that I haven't been able to find anywhere.

In a STM32F415 I want the Output Compare of a timer to be high by default, and low for the number of clock cycles I tell him. My aim is to **disable** one timer using another timer. In the [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf) page 620, there's an example on *Using one timer to enable another timer*.

In my case, I want TIM3 to control TIM2 and TIM4 to control TIM5. TIM2 and TIM5 are triggering DAC requests to the DMA, and they are working fine.

This is how I initialise TIM3 (this function is called in *main* before the infinite loop):

```
void TIM3_Config(void)
{
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef     TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
TIM_OCInitTypeDef           TIM_OCInitBaseStructure;

TIM_DeInit(TIM3);

// TIM3 Periph clock enable
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3, ENABLE);

// Time base configuration
TIM_TimeBaseStructInit(&TIM_TimeBaseStructure);
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 0x46;        //ARR = 70 (cycles low will be 0-63)
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

// TIM3 Output Compare configuration
TIM_OCStructInit(&TIM_OCInitBaseStructure);
TIM_OCInitBaseStructure.TIM_OCMode=TIM_OCMode_Active;
TIM_OCInitBaseStructure.TIM_Pulse=0x3C;   //CCR
TIM_OCInitBaseStructure.TIM_OutputState=TIM_OutputState_Enable;
TIM_OC1Init(TIM3,&TIM_OCInitBaseStructure);
TIM3->CCMR1 &= 0xFFF7;      // OC1PE: Output compare 1 preload disabled
TIM3->CCMR1 &= 0xFFFC;      //  CC1S[1:0]=00 CC1 channel is configured as output.
TIM3->CR1 |= 0x8;
TIM3->CR2 |= 0x40;
TIM_SelectOutputTrigger(TIM3, TIM_TRGOSource_OC1Ref);       //  MSM[2:0] = 100 OC1REF as TIM3 TRGO

TIM_Cmd(TIM3, ENABLE);
}
```

Then, in the corresponding DMA IRQ handler:

```
void DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler(void)           /* DAC2 */
{

if (DMA_GetITStatus(DMA1_Stream6,DMA_IT_HTIF6) == SET)
{
    DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA1_Stream6,DMA_IT_HTIF6);

    TIM3->CNT  = 0x0;     // Reset timer
    TIM3->CR1 |= 0x1;     // Enable timer
}
/* Some code for the Transfer Complete case */
}
```

In another point of the program I change the CCR according to the number of cycles I want the slave timer (TIM2 or TIM5) to be disabled.

My main problem is that it doesn't work at all, and while debugging I've found that TIM3 and TIM4 enable instructions seem to do nothing: the enable bit (CEN in the TIMx CR1 register) stays '0' instead of changing to '1'. TIM2 and TIM5 initialisation are pretty much the same, without the Output Compare and with the gated input configuration to the corresponding timer TRGO, and they can be enabled and disabled without problems.

I haven't found any condition or limitation to how I should enable a Timer that could affect my program so I'm a bit lost with this.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: TL;DR, but: don't use that bloatware STlib/"HAL". It does not make your code any bit more portable, but slows it down by adding unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

When the `OPM` bit is set, the `CEN` bit is reset to 0 as soon as the counter finishes, so perhaps everything is working correctly, but you can't see it, because it's happening too fast. Set some bits in the APB freeze registers, `DBGMCU->APB1_FZ` in your case, if you want to examine the timers with a debugger. Or slow down everything to a crawl, I did it with using prescalers, and running the core on the internal HSI clock without PLL.

Nevertheless, I can only agree with what seems to be the majority opinion here, that using SPL or HAL for timers is just a waste of various resources (of the programmer and the controller). Working with registers produces shorter, simpler code, and it's quite portable too. I've actually tested this on a STM32L1, but I'm quite sure it would work on a F415 too.

```
#define PRESCALER   0xFFFFU
#define TDELAY      8U

void gatedtimer(void) {
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN | RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN;
    RCC->APB1RSTR = RCC_APB1RSTR_TIM2RST | RCC_APB1RSTR_TIM3RST;
    RCC->APB1RSTR = 0;

    TIM2->PSC = PRESCALER;  // a BIG prescaler to slow things down to observable speed
    TIM2->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG; // force prescaler update
    TIM3->PSC = PRESCALER;  // same prescaler to all timers
    TIM3->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG; // force prescaler update
    // of course you should omit the above in production code

    TIM2->SMCR = (0b010U << TIM_SMCR_TS_Pos)    // Trigger selection ITR2 = TIM3
               | (0b101U << TIM_SMCR_SMS_Pos);  // Gated Mode
    TIM2->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN; // start the slave

    TIM3->CR2   = (0b100U << TIM_CR2_MMS_Pos); // "100: Compare - OC1REF signal is used as trigger output (TRGO)"
    TIM3->CCMR1 = (0b110U << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos); // "110: PWM mode 1 - In upcounting, channel 1 is active as long as TIMx_CNT < TIMx_CCR1 else inactive."
    TIM3->CCR1 = TDELAY;    // "some delay" is required for the timer hw to start a pulse

    while(TIM2->CNT < 20U)
        printf("TIM2->CNT=%lu TIM3->CNT=%lu\n", TIM2->CNT, TIM3->CNT); // slave runs normally

    TIM3->ARR = TDELAY + 30; // set delay length
    TIM3->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN | TIM_CR1_OPM; // start the master in one pulse mode

    while(TIM3->CR1 & TIM_CR1_CEN) // CEN bit will be reset
        printf("TIM2->CNT=%lu TIM3->CNT=%lu\n", TIM2->CNT, TIM3->CNT); // slave stops when master CNT reaches TDELAY
    while(TIM2->CNT < 40)
        printf("TIM2->CNT=%lu TIM3->CNT=%lu\n", TIM2->CNT, TIM3->CNT); // slave resumes counting
}
```